# Unable to locate an element using text attribute in XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath

[image: Element description]

I am trying to locate element using relative XPath. I have attached HTML schema of the element. Below is the XPath I am using:
`//a[contains(text(),"Sales")]`.

Comment: Show more of your HTML (as code-formatted text, not an image, please).   Since `"Sales"` is part of a `::before` CSS pseudo-element, you'll need some other criteria to select against if you want to use XPath here.

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ ?

Comment: How is going? Did you try my answer?

Comment: I was trying to use css selector with text. Yeah link text works fine though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to locate link by text you might need to use search by link text instead of XPath:

- Java:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sales")).click();
  ```
- Python:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sales").click()
  ```

Note that you should use exact value as it appears on rendered page in browser:

- if it appears as `SALES`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("SALES")
  ```
- if it appears as `"Sales"`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("\"Sales\"")
  ```

In case some extra text is added by `::before` pseudo-element, you can also use search by partial link text:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Sales")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[@class='**your class name**']//*[text()='Sales']
```

Hope above XPath helps you!